# what is the difference between write actionperformed in run() or outside of main

Tags: swing

I write action performed code like outside of main

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextField1.setText("do something");
}
```

and it can be written in run() like

```
       jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jTextField1.setText("aaaaaaaaaa");
            }
        });
```

what is the difference between this two is there any programming overhead related issue or not which is the better coding style.

i am using netbeans when i write it in run() it will demand to make the jTextField1 to static becauce main mathod is static so i think firstone is not good because it will occupy memory until programme is stoped.am i correct?

2.if i want to do that all buttons actions are written in different class then how can i implement this in swing form.

Comment: `run()` method of which class? `Runnable`, `Thread` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to keep your main as small as possible, reduce it to just a call to the constructor and a setVisible(true).

```
    public void run() {
        new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
```

The reason for that is that you may need to reuse your class in an other application. It is always better to create all your widgets in the class, keeping the Netbeans layout.

If you use the second option, and happen to need to use `this`, it will refer to the ActionListener and not to the Swing widget your class is extending.

In order to put your ActionListener in another class make a class like this:

```
public class AListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("B1"))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B1 clicked!");
        else  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("B2"))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B2 clicked!");
    }

}
```

and add the ActionListener to your button in the constructor after NB's initComponents() like that:

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    ActionListener al = new AListener();
    jButton1.addActionListener(al);
    jButton2.addActionListener(al);
}
```

For this to work you have to add the appropriate setActionCommand Strings for every button:

```
    jButton1.setActionCommand("B1");
    jButton2.setActionCommand("B2");
```

In Netbeans it can easily be done if you change the Post-Creation code of every button to include the String it is supposed to.

I think in "normal" cases (where you do not have 60 buttons, or so), it may still be better to stick to the standards. It is a matter of taste how you design your application.

Most of the time the actions of an application have to share data details that are local to your class. In order to avoid passing that information to your AListener explicitly, and in order to be able to use `this`, keep your ActionListeners together inside the class you are using.

Comment: but it is not clear like crystal if i have so many button and every button have different action then what i do i create many aListner like class and every class have actionPerformed() method where i  will define the action.what is difference between call it  in constructor NewJFrame or define in run().if you give an example it will better for me because i am new in swing.

Comment: In case you have many buttons, you can still use one ActionListener, but it will help to use: public void setActionCommand(String command) and public String getActionCommand(String command). I will add a sample to my answer after my Netbeans installation is done... :-)

Comment: I have changed the example above to support 2 buttons with one ActionListener class. I think you should better forget about defining things inside main-run. The code re-usability alone is reason enough. Also consider that you will have to define everything as static.